# Way to Automatically Add a LinqToSql base class to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there an automatic way to add base classes to Linq2Sql entities?

I know I can define a partial and implement that but there has to be an automated way, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LINQ-to-SQL code-generator supports this directly.

The base-class for the data-context can be set in the designer, as the `Base Class` property. Alternatively, edit the dbml directly: right click, "Edit With...", "XML Editor"

To change the base class for the entities, set the type:

```
<Database EntityBase="Some.NameSpace.Foo" ... >
```

To change the base class for the data-context, set the type:

```
<Database BaseType="Some.NameSpace.Bar" ... >
```

In both cases, use the fully-qualified type in the attribute. Et voila.

Note that because it is very literal, you can also use this approach to make your entities implement an interface - for example, when my classes have properties like `LastUpdated` and `UpdatedBy`, I might have an `IAuditable` interface that defines these. Then I can put code in my data-context's `SubmitChanges` (override) that calls `GetChangeSet()` and sets these values for all the `IAuditable` entities being updated; very sweet.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411515/way-to-automatically-add-a-linqtosql-base-class-to-entities#411903) is clearly the right way to go in this case, but I'm leaving this answer here for posterity - it's a handy trick to know about in some cases, where you only need a partial class to change the inheritance/interfaces of a class.

I don't know of any automated way, but if you wanted to do this for multiple classes and *only* wanted to specify the base class, you might consider creating a file just for the partial class declarations. I use this approach in Protocol Buffers to make the internal representation classes which are autogenerated implement a particular interface.

See [PartialClasses.cs](http://github.com/jskeet/dotnet-protobufs/tree/master/src/ProtocolBuffers/DescriptorProtos/PartialClasses.cs) for this example as code. (Ignore the TODO - it's fixed locally, but I haven't pushed for a little while :)

Comment: "I know I can define a partial and implement that but there has to be an automated way, right?"  -1, sorry Skeet, but that wasn't helpful

Comment: So if there *is* no automated way, are you going to downvote everyone, even if they're still trying to make your code more manageable? Yes, you knew about creating your own partial class - but you may not have thought of putting them all in one file to avoid a source file explosion.

Comment: Not necessarily, your answer is particularly bad because the only additional info you've provided is "you can put multiple classes in a single file".

Comment: And why is that additional info "particularly bad"? It's a valid way of making the code more manageable IMO - it would be easy to write something to automatically generate such a file if you really wanted to, and if not it's trivial to keep up to date anyway. Much simpler than multiple tiny files.

Comment: (Having said all this, the template approach suggested by Todd is great *if* you don't want to also use DBML. I'm just pointing out an alternative to make your life easier if the only thing you want to change is how you specify a base class.)

Comment: ridiculous comments... Thanks for your answer! I used a similar approach and was (until now) not really sure if this idea is approved somehow. Now iKnow.. Just sayin ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some people have written their own code templates in place of the DBML approach. Going that route you can easily add the base classes yourself.

[LINQ to SQL template for Visual Studio 2008](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/09/14/linq-to-sql-template-for-visual-studio-2008) is a good starting point