# LINQ to SQL does not support casting?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, linq-to-sql, casting

If I do this:

```
User userOOM = new User();
userOOM.Nickname = "markzzz";

UserFacebook userFacebook = new UserFacebook();
userFacebook.first_name = "marco";

db.User.InsertOnSubmit(userOOM);
userOOM.UserFacebook.Add(userFacebook);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

the insert is perfect, and it works. But, if I do this:

```
User userOOM = new User();
userOOM.Nickname = "markzzz";

UserFacebookCatcher userCatched = new UserFacebookCatcher();
UserFacebook userFacebook = (UserFacebook)userCatched;
userFacebook.first_name = "marco";

db.User.InsertOnSubmit(userOOM);
userOOM.UserFacebook.Add(userFacebook);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

(so, I cast the `userFacebook` class) I got a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception. It works if I remove:

```
userOOM.UserFacebook.Add(userFacebook);
```

so the casting is the problem. `UserFacebookCatcher` is nothing special:

```
public class UserFacebookCatcher : UserFacebook
{
    public UserFacebookCatcher()
    {
        this.first_name = "marco"
    }
}
```

LINQ to SQL does not work if I inherit a class?

Comment: 1) There's no need for an explicit cast there; it can be implicitly converted.  2) Which line throws the exception?

Comment: 1) even if I do `UserFacebook userFacebook = userCatched;` I got the Exception. 2)The line on `db.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: Also, if with debug I watch at `userFacebook` field, the `first_name` is "marco", so it is not null!!!!

Comment: @markzzz, you've ensured your familiar with the contents of [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707366(v=vs.91).aspx)?

Comment: Uhm, but what's about that articles? It explains query and addictional parameters on the new class. I'm just inhreit it, populating the fields of the parent class in the costructor :O

Comment: Tried adding `KnownType(typeof(UserFacebookCatcher))` at the `UserFacebook` class, but nothing change... I always get that exception!

Comment: Is it inside `db.SubmitChanges()` or could `db` actually be null?

Comment: No db it is not null because, as I specified, if I just use `UserFacebook userFacebook = new UserFacebook(); userFacebook.first_name = "marco";` it works!

Comment: Does the stack trace of the exception give any clues?

Comment: Not really! Just Object null :O

Comment: Check this link an get some idea about Linq with inheritance http://stackoverflow.com/a/494942/3156647